# How to use picture in Listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

How to use a picture in the Android `listview`? How to design a layout that enables us to put images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want images in a ListView you're going to need to define a custom layout for your list items. You can place an ImageView in that layout and then in your getView or newView/bindView (depending on the Adapter class you extend), you can modify the ImageView to contain whatever graphic you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

you can get help from

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/listview-with-icon.html

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg15691.html

http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip

hope this will helps you if not yet then tell me

Answer (score 1):

Make a new file in /res/layout/demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/os_name"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your class file--

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row, R.id.os_name, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

In the list you will get the text with image.